# Can I call a constructor to be run infinitly - javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

So I'm using paper.js to make a game, and I want to make infinitely spawning platforms that fall from the top of the screen, I was wondering if I should do that by calling the constructor within the update method every 50 frames, if not, how else should I do this.

P.S. I am using paper.js (a library you can find online) to do this.

```
 class Platform extends Entity{
     constructor(){
      super([400, 60], [0, 0], [0, 0], "black", new Path.Rectangle({
       size: [100, 30],
       fillColor: "black",
       strokeColor: "black"
      }));
     }
     update(event) {
      this.vy = 3;  
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. you would shortly run out of ram. I would create a js script that destroys then creates a replacement platform. Could you explain how the spawning is supposed to work?

Comment: Whats your plan ? Do you want the application to run or not? lol

Comment: If you want to make infinitely platform objects then you need another object to create them (and then destroy them when needed i.e. when hitting the ground or going out of the page). Do you see what I mean?